# Styling pagination in twenty twelve theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pagination

I'm using WordPress twenty twelve theme as parent theme. I wanted to add numbered pagination to it so I found this code and I added it to my function.php file:

```
<?php
```

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentytwelve_content_nav' ) ) :
    function twentytwelve_content_nav() {
        global $wp_query;

```
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
}
```

endif;
?>
which really worked fine the problem is I failed to add css styling as It is not warped in any ID or class which limits my ability to style it the way I planed. Is there any way to add class or Id to this code so I can style it?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Wordpress codec, and there is no way to add a class or id in the paginate_links function.

Why not just wrap the echo statement in a container div?

```
?><div class="paginated-links"><?php
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?></div><?php
```

**EDIT:** To use this, replace the following code, with the code above:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: thank you, I'm confused about what should I do with your code snippet

Comment: I've edited my answer to include instructions with the code to replace with my code.

Comment: I may sound like a dumb but still don't get it! do you suggest to replace the code ( in my functions.php file) which adds numbered pagination with yours or am missing something?

Comment: Ok, this is the code you have: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zLukxaH1 , replace it with this code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SgwShgq4 in you functions.php file.

Comment: thanks anyway man! but this only triggers the default ( newer and older posts navigation )

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
<?php $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>
    <?php 
     $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $wpquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged'=>$page
    ));

    while ($wpquery->have_posts()) {
        $wpquery->the_post();
        ?>

            <li class="contentlist">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></p>
            </li>



        <?php
    }

     ?>

     <?php 



    global $wpquery;
    if( $wpquery->max_num_pages >1){
      $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

      echo paginate_links( array(
     'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
     'format' => '?paged=%#%',
     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
     'total' => $wpquery->max_num_pages
       ) );
   }

     ?>
```

functions.php

```
// Pagination for each category
function custom_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_ppp' );

?>
```